# Combining patented products

Tags: law, licensing, creams

I have found 4 patented products combined together created a cream that has amazing results on burns and non-specific skin conditions.  Am I able to patent my product?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, unless someone else has already disclosed this combination or the combination is an obvious one.  But be warned, you must be able to acquire those four patented products to make your product, and your patent doesn't excuse you from needing to acquire a license in some manner for those four components, either by buying the supplies from a licensed dealer or directly licensing the patents from the patent holders.

Comment: Thats not entirely true, depending on wording and scope of the patents, you might be able to get around them and still get the same result. Thats case dependend.